# How to replace 2 characters if they are side by side in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, sed, tr

I'm looking to replace 2 characters in a string only if they are side by side.

Output I have now

```
hu1.cqf51:qu-2/2
hu2.cqf55:qe-2/2
hu2.cqf41:qe-2/2
```

The first line is incorrect as it has "qu" instead of "qe"
I'm looking to replace the qu with qe without replacing any other "q" or "e" in the string

Desired output

```
hu1.cqf51:qe-2/2
hu2.cqf55:qe-2/2
hu2.cqf41:qe-2/2
```

What I have tried

`sed -r 's/[qu]+/qe/g'`
`sed -e 's//qe/g'`
`sed 's/\S*\(qu\)\S*//g'`

Even considered just trying to delete the whole word alone if it matched with the command below, however it deleted everything with a q or u in it.
`sed -e 's/[^ ]*qu[^ ]*//g'`

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: How do you want to treat a line `hu3.qux:qe-2/2` or a line `qu4:cqf41:qe-2/2`?

Comment: Why isn't `s/qu/qe/` all you need?

Answer (score 0):

Can you just try this ?

```
sed -e 's/qu/qe/' your_file
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest

```
sed 's/:qu-/:qe-/'
```

but if this is a standard format there is probably a standard way.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike tr, sed automatically matches the whole pattern without any options. This works with your example:

```
sed 's/qu/qe/g'
```